# Smarty if statement

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

First time I use smarty so please don't be evil..
hope that someone could help me with this problem.
I have the following code in page.tpl:

```
{$user-status}
{if $user-status == '-'}
    <h1>OK</h1>
{/if}
```

When the page is loaded, I see

```
"user-status-string" // this is correct
    {if $user-status == '-'}
        <h1>OK</h1>
    {/if}
```

It shows exactly the code as I have written, though above shows the correct variable attribute.
Does someone know what i am doing wrong?

Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I guess that naming a variable with a dash can lead to unwanted behavior from Smarty.

Try to assign and use a variable named `$userStatus` for example.

Comment: The cache file looks correct. Tried with {if 'a' eq 'b'}{/if}:
In cache <?php if ('a'=='b'){?> <? } ?>
and the generated HTML I see {if 'a' eq 'b'} {/if}!!!
What the hell?!

Comment: Maybe check your compile/cache directory locations? (with `$smarty->getCompileDir()` and `$smarty->getCacheDir()`)